# Sending POST and PUT requests from Android app to MySQL database using Spring RestTemplate and fasterxlm jackon

Tags: android, mysql, spring, jackson, resttemplate

I'm making an Android app that reads and writes data from MySQL database on my pc via shared wi-fi connection. Some of the data are in the form of my own class.
I successfully set up the server and I already managed to GET some data from my databes following [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg5SPLyQsUQ).

I somewhat know what I need to do, but my problem is what the format of methods should be for POST and PUT.

Parts of my code that work for GET:

My request is created like this:

```
//get user by name
@RequestMapping(path="/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public  User getUserByName(@PathVariable("name") String name) {return 
userService.getUserByName(name);}
```

In a client class in my app:

```
// get user by name
public User getUserByName(String name){
return restTemplate.exchange(REST_SERVICE_URI + "/" + name, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<User>() {}).getBody();}
```

and later used by a class inside my activity

private class

```
HttpRequestAsk extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User>{
    private String name;

    public HttpRequestAsk(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected User doInBackground(Void... params){
        UserRestClient userRestClient = new UserRestClient();
        User emptyUser = new User();
        emptyUser.emptyUser();
        if(userRestClient.getUserByName(name) == null) return emptyUser;
        else return userRestClient.getUserByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(User user) {

            EditText passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordField);
            TextView loginStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LoginStateTextView);
            String fail = "Login Failed";
            String success = "Login Succeeded";

        if(user.getName().equals("empty")) loginStateTextView.setText(fail) ;
        else if (user.getPassword().equals(passwordText.getText().toString())) {
                loginStateTextView.setText(success);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListSelectActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Extra user data", (Serializable) user);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else loginStateTextView.setText(fail);
    }
}
```

Then on button click I call execute() for HttpRequestAsk and I get the user.

Now, let's say I want to call this request

```
//add new user
@RequestMapping(path="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNewUser(@RequestBody User user){
    if( !user.getEmail().contains("@") || !user.getEmail().contains(".") ) return "Invalid email";
    else if( userService.getUserByName(user.getName()) == null && userService.getUserByEmail(user.getEmail()) == null) {
        userService.addUser(user);
        return "Saved a user";
    }else if( userService.getUserByName(user.getName()) != null && userService.getUserByEmail(user.getEmail() ) != null ) return "Username and email already in use";
    else if( userService.getUserByName(user.getName()) != null ) return "Username already in use";
    else return "Email already in use";
}
```

I tried to POST a user like this

```
//add new user
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void addNewUser(User user){
    restTemplate.postForLocation(REST_SERVICE_URI + "/add", user, User.class);
}
```

But the app crashes when I use this addNewUser method. I guess I should make and Entity or JSON out of my user, kind of reverse what I did with GET, but I don't really know how.